# Riyadh Airport Transit No visa?

Tags: visas, transit, uk-citizens, saudi-arabia, self-transfer

I have a Wizz air flight that lands in Riyadh airport, then 2hrs 25mins later I have a Flynas flight to Mumbai. Can I transit directly to the different Terminal, and do I need a visa? I hold a United Kingdom passport

Comment: That is an extremely risky self-transfer. I certainly hope you don’t have checked bags.

Comment: Even if this is allowed (there seems to be some uncertainty in prior questions here about which terminals you can get between in Riyadh without passing immigration), consider the risks if this doesn't work out. If your Wizz Air flight is delayed, it's late enough in the day that there's a high chance you're stuck in the Riyadh airport at least overnight without a visa (on certain days of the week, you might be able to try to buy a last-minute seat on a late night Saudia flight if you don't have checked bags).